# Cannot reproduce behavior of geom_col() when multiple values per group (instead of one) are supplied

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I came across this problem by accident. My goal was to use `geom_col()` to represent a single value (the sum in this case). I forgot the `summarise()` step at first and it gave me the first plot (see below). When I noticed that I fixed it and calculated the sum and got the second plot.

After reading a bit about it, `geom_col()` should indeed take the sum of the values in case multiple value per group are given, correct? However, when I compare my two plots, this doesn't seem to be the case.

It may just be something obvious that I am missing but I cannot figure it out.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
d <- structure(list(year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
                             2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), score = c(0.17, 12.17, 0, 0, 0, 0.67, 
                                                                0, 7.83, 0, 14, 0), study = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                                                                                              "A", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(study, score, group = as.factor(year))) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(year)), position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =  c(0,30))
```

[image]

```r
d %>% 
  group_by(year, study) %>% 
  summarise(score = sum(score), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(study, score, group = as.factor(year))) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(year)), position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =  c(0,30))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_col` is essentially just `geom_bar` with `stat = stat_identity()`. It doesn't add up multiple values if they are in the same fill group and on the same point of the x axis. We can confirm this by giving the columns an outline and making them partially transparent:

```r
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(study, score, group = as.factor(year))) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(year)), position = position_dodge(),
           color = 'black', alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits =  c(0,30))
```

[image]

Notice that the bars are simply overlaid on each other.

When you say:

> After reading a bit about it, `geom_col()` should indeed take the sum of the values in case multiple value per group are given

Can you show us where you read this?

Comment: OK, so the tallest bar is the max value within that fill grouping? As for your question, I should have said "After reading about it, **I concluded**, `geom_col` [...] ". Thanks for pointing that out. I clearly misunderstood (and still are trying to make sense of it) what I read and tried, for example I also tried this `ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) + geom_col()` and seems to add up all the values in the `Species` group, e.g. it is not taking a unique value. After your answer I went back, added a white outline and here it seems they are stacked (appears like a sum) and not overlaid.

Comment: Never mind, I think I get it now. When you don't have a grouping variable specified it stacks the individual bars. If a grouping is applied, the values are overlayed, which makes sense I guess since in that case you would want to compare the individuals within in the group to each other, e.g. `IRIS$year =2008; ggplot(IRIS, aes(as.factor(year), Sepal.Length, group = Species)) + geom_col(aes(fill = as.factor(Species)), position = position_dodge(), col = "white", alpha = 0.3)`. Although the `iris` dataset is a terrible example for that.